# I cannot understand a proof of the Extreme Value Theorem by Masahiko Saito.

Tags: calculus, continuity, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I am reading "Calculus" by Masahiko Saito.

There is the following theorem in this book:

> Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $[a, b]$. Then $f(x)$ attains a maximum value.

And the proof by Masahiko Saito is like the following:

> Let $S_n := \{a, a+\frac{b-a}{n}, a+2\frac{(b-a)}{n}, \cdots, a+(n-1)\frac{(b-a)}{n}, b\}$.
> Let $a_n := \min\{x \in S_n\mid f(x) = \max\{f(y) \mid y \in S_n\}\}$.
> $\{a_n\}$ is bounded.
> So, there is a subsequence $\{a_{\phi(n)}\}$ of $\{a_n\}$ which converges.
> Let $c := \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{\phi(n)}$.
> Then, $c \in [a, b]$.
> Assume that there exists $d\in [a, b]$ such that $f(c) < f(d)$.
> For $\epsilon := f(d)-f(c) > 0$, there exists $\delta >0$ such that if $x \in [a, b]$ and $|x-d|< \delta$, then $|f(x) - f(d)| < \epsilon$.
> $\therefore$ If $x \in [a, b]$ and $|x-d|< \delta$, then $f(c) < f(x)$.
> Let $n$ be a positive integer such that $\frac{1}{\delta} < n$.
> Then, there exists $u \in S_n$ such that $d-\delta < u < d+\delta$.
> Then, $f(u) \leq f(a_n) \leq f(c)$.
> And this is a contradiction.

***I cannot understand why $f(a_n) \leq f(c)$ holds.***
***Please tell me why $f(a_n) \leq f(c)$ holds in the above proof.***

Since I cannot understand the proof by Masahiko Saito, I modified his proof as follows:

> Let $S_n := \{a, a+\frac{b-a}{2^n}, a+2\frac{(b-a)}{2^n}, \cdots, a+(2^n-1)\frac{(b-a)}{2^n}, b\}$.
> Let $a_n := \min\{x \in S_n\mid f(x) = \max\{f(y) \mid y \in S_n\}\}$.
> $\{a_n\}$ is bounded.
> So, there is a subsequence $\{a_{\phi(n)}\}$ of $\{a_n\}$ which converges.
> Let $c := \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{\phi(n)}$.
> Then, $c \in [a, b]$.
> Since $\{f(a_{n})\}$ is a monotonic increasing sequence and $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(a_{\phi(n)})=f(c)$, so $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(a_{n})=f(c)$.
> Assume that there exists $d\in [a, b]$ such that $f(c) < f(d)$.
> For $\epsilon := f(d)-f(c) > 0$, there exists $\delta >0$ such that if $x \in [a, b]$ and $|x-d|< \delta$, then $|f(x) - f(d)| < \epsilon$.
> $\therefore$ If $x \in [a, b]$ and $|x-d|< \delta$, then $f(c) < f(x)$.
> Let $n$ be a positive integer such that $\frac{1}{\delta} < 2^n$.
> Then, there exists $u \in S_n$ such that $d-\delta < u < d+\delta$.
> Then, $f(u) \leq f(a_n) \leq f(c)$.
> And this is a contradiction.

***Is my proof ok?***

Comment: Your proof is ok, and in the first you get $f(a_n) \leqslant f(c)$ by an argument similar to the given. Suppose $f(a_n) - f(c) = \varepsilon > 0$. There is $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert f(x) - f(p)\rvert < \varepsilon/2$ for $\lvert x-p\rvert < \delta$, where $p$ can be either of $a_n$ and $c$. For large enough $m$, there are points $b_m$ in $S_m$ with $f(b_m) > f(c) + \varepsilon/2$, whence $\lvert a_m - c\rvert \geqslant \delta$. That's your contradiction. In short, your proof is much better.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you very much for your answer.